# How to add custom icons to the Shopware 6 plattform?

Tags: svg, icons, shopware

How can I add my custom SVG Icons to Shopware 6 and used it like in the official documentation:

https://component-library.shopware.com/components/sw-icon/

Like:
`<sw-icon name="mycustom-shape-heart" color="#fc427b"></sw-icon>`

Comment: If you can add Javascript, you can add a Custom Element, see https://iconmeister.github.io

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately it is not possible "out of the box" via plugin.

The SVG icons of the `development/platform` are automatically loaded via webpack and `svg-inline-loader`. All icons are being collected and a small component gets created for each SVG icon. You can find the core icons and logic here: `platform/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/app/assets/icons`.

However you could do something similar in your plugin. It is possible to create a custom webpack config here:

```
YouPlugin
- src
   - Resources
     - app
       - administration
         - build
           - webpack.config.js <-- custom webpack config
         - src
           - app
             - assets
               - icons
                 - svg <-- Your SVG icons
                 - icons.js <-- Component creation
```

Then you basically do the same as the core but with your own icons:

```js
const path = require('path');

function resolve(dir) {
    return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir);
}

module.exports = function () {
    return {
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.svg$/,
                    include: [
                        resolve('src/app/assets/icons/svg')
                    ],
                    loader: 'svg-inline-loader',
                    options: {
                        removeSVGTagAttrs: false
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    };
};
```

And in your icons.js:

```js
export default (() => {
    const context = require.context('./svg', false, /svg$/);

    return context.keys().reduce((accumulator, item) => {
        const componentName = item.split('.')[1].split('/')[1];
        const component = {
            name: componentName,
            functional: true,
            render(createElement, elementContext) {
                const data = elementContext.data;

                return createElement('span', {
                    class: [data.staticClass, data.class],
                    style: data.style,
                    attrs: data.attrs,
                    on: data.on,
                    domProps: {
                        innerHTML: context(item)
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        accumulator.push(component);
        return accumulator;
    }, []);
})();
```

If you only have a few icons this might be overkill. Maybe you could consider another approach like this (just for the plugin) and use another component like `<custom-icon>`: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/editable-svg-icons.html

Comment: I did it in this way. Maybe not the ideal solution but it works:https://forum.shopware.com/discussion/69422/wie-kann-man-das-bestehende-icon-system-mit-eigenen-svgs-erweitern#latest

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a custom component and add SVG icon code in the component's twig file.

**NOTE: component's name should start with `"icons-"` like 'icons-my-custom-icon'**

Then you can use that icon with the `sw-icon` tag like:

```
<sw-icon name="my-custom-icon"></sw-icon>
```

Answer (score -3):

The solution for me was as described here (German only): https://forum.shopware.com/discussion/69422/wie-kann-man-das-bestehende-icon-system-mit-eigenen-svgs-erweitern#latest